# Unable to skip Jenkins Build by SCM Skip Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am working on a pipeline script in Jenkins to build the project based on a commit message. From Jenkins' forum, I noticed that we can use SCM skip plugin. I installed the plugin and added the below stage as the forum suggests:

```
scmSkip(deleteBuild: true, skipPattern:'.*\\[ci skip\\].*')
```

When I commit a change with the following commit message:

```
git commit -m "[ci skip] Updated Audit Test Data Files with scan status"
```

The build is not skipped. It progresses with the other stages.

In console logs, I see the message

> SCM Skip: Changelog is empty!

How do I construct the scmSkip call to skip the build when a commit message including "[ci skip]" is found? Are there alternatives that are easier to implement?

Thanks,
Karthik P.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you didn't checkout first the repository

Comment: which means what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you aren't skipping the scm default checkout (via skipDefaultCheckout true) on the node where the build is running.

```
pipeline {
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout false
    }

    stages {
        stage('Check for Skip') {
            steps {
                scmSkip(deleteBuild: true, skipPattern:'.*\\[ci skip\\].*')
            }
        }

...
```